# Multiple Django apps used for multiple authentication role

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

Using MySql in BackEnd.

There are two roles, **Customer and Vendor**.I have to use custom authentication for both of them.
I have generated two apps customer and vendor,i was successful in overwriting Django's AUTH_USER_MODEL by using class User(AbstractBaseUser): model in customer app which created the table customer_user replacing the auth_user table provided by Django in default.
[custom auth_user_model for customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTW1j.png)

Now similarly I want to create vendor_user table in the database, with custom authentication for Vendor App.
What I have noticed is by default Django provides single authentication model for single project.
How do I creater multiple custom authentication model for the project?

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying I never used any system (Django or not) where there was many user tables, one for each user role. Always there was only one user table shared between every user in the system no matter which roles they play. When you don't see some setup in the wild often it means it does not work, so my advice is: no matter what strategy you pick, or what is your business model, always use one, and only one Django model to handle the authentication.

If you need to maintain extra information related to the users, you have to ask yourself if this particular information is relevant to all users or if it is relevant to only some type of users. For example, a “customer number” may only be relevant to Customer users. In such cases, you are better off adding a profile model via one-to-one relationship. Now, if the extra info is relevant to all users (e.g., avatar image), the best thing to do is add an extra field directly to the User model.

You may have a "role" field and use inheritance or one-to-one relationships in order to link this base user model to the profile-specific models. I've used both inheritance and foreign keys and I prefer a foreignkey to a profile model instead of model inheritance (model inheritance is implemented using one-to-one relationships anyway so I would rather be explicit about it).

You can have something like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ROLES = (
        ('customer', 'Customer'),
        ('vendor', 'Vendor'),
    )
    ...
    role = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ROLES)
    vendor_profile = models.OneToOneField(
                         VendorProfile, 
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         blank=True, null=True) 
    customer_profile = models.OneToOneField(
                         CustomerProfile, 
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    @property
    def profile(self):
        if self.role == 'vendor':
            if not self.vendor_profile_id:
                self.vendor_profile = VendorProfile.objects.create()
                if self.pk:
                    self.save()
            return self.vendor_profile
        if not self.customer_profile_id:
            self.vendor_profile = CustomerProfile.objects.create()
            if self.pk:
                self.save()
        return self.customer_profile
```

But it is not fully transparent - for example if you ever have to filter a queryset based on specific role model fields you must use `vendor_profile__foo='Bar'` or `customer_profile__foo='Bar'` depending on the user role. You may also have to purge dangling profiles from time to time because using the above property you may create a profile before saving the user object.

In the end there are many alternatives for handling multiple user types each one with its trade-off and it is a matter of taste - but IMHO spreading usernames and passwords across several models is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks Paulo, this was helpful.